# Error while working with Android and Existing SQLite Database, file is encrypted or is not a database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sdk, mobility

My database contain 5000 records I wanted to fetch those records in Cursor object.

Here my DBHelper.java

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
    import android.util.Log;

    public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        private static String DB_NAME = "StudentDetails";
        private SQLiteDatabase db;
        private final Context context;
        private String DB_PATH;

        public DBHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
            this.context = context;
            DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + "databases/";
        }

        public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

            boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
            if (dbExist) {

            } else {
                this.getReadableDatabase();
                try {
                    copyDataBase();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new Error("Error copying database");
                }
            }
        }

        private boolean checkDataBase() {
            File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
            return dbFile.exists();
        }

        private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

            InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
            String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            // Close the streams
            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();
            myInput.close();

        }

        public Cursor getData() {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
            Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Student where Phone='4085551212ll'",null);

        }
        public void getAllMembers()
        {
            Cursor c = getData();
            if(c == null)
            {
                Log.d("No data", "Cursornot initialized.....");
            }

            String name;
            c.moveToFirst();
            do {
                Log.d("Data", "Able to fetch ..........");
                name = c.getString(1);
                Log.d("Values",name);

            } while (c.moveToNext());
            c.close();
        }
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
}
```

My MainActivity.java

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.io.IOException;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Button button;
    private DBHelper databaseHelper;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //R - Resource
        databaseHelper = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());

        button  =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBless);

        databaseHelper = new DBHelper(this);
        try {
            databaseHelper.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        databaseHelper.getAllMembers();

    }
}
```

As a layout I have only a Button.
And in asset folder I have pasted my file **StudentDetails**.

Is .sqlite extension is important ?
But I have tried in both case its not working getting exception on logcat.
Java Binder Exception.

I have debug it, I am able to copy that database file but whenever I am clicking on Button I am getting following Error in logcat.

**Log CAT**

```
08-15 00:14:21.796: E/SQLiteLog(2291): (26) file is encrypted or is not a database
08-15 00:14:21.796: D/AndroidRuntime(2291): Shutting down VM
08-15 00:14:21.796: D/AndroidRuntime(2291): --------- beginning of crash
08-15 00:14:21.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2291): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-15 00:14:21.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2291): Process: com.chahalnet.myadroid.mysos, PID: 2291
08-15 00:14:21.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2291): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
08-15 00:14:21.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2291):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4007)
08-15 00:14:21.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2291):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
08-15 00:14:21.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2291):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
08-15 00:14:21.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2291):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
08-15 00:14:21.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2291):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-15 00:14:21.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2291):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
08-15 00:14:21.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2291):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
08-15 00:14:21.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2291):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-15 00:14:21.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2291):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
08-15 00:14:21.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2291):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
08-15 00:14:21.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2291):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
08-15 00:14:21.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2291): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-15 00:14:21.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2291):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-15 00:14:21.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2291):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
08-15 00:14:21.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2291):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4002)
08-15 00:14:21.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2291):     ... 10 more
08-15 00:14:21.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2291): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException: file is encrypted or is not a database (code 26): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM Members where Phone='4085551212ll'
08-15 00:14:21.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2291):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
08-15 00:14:21.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2291):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
08-15 00:14:21.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2291):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
08-15 00:14:21.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2291):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
08-15 00:14:21.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2291):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
08-15 00:14:21.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2291):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
08-15 00:14:21.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2291):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
08-15 00:14:21.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2291):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
08-15 00:14:21.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2291):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1255)
08-15 00:14:21.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2291):     at com.chahalnet.myadroid.mysos.DBHelper.getData(DBHelper.java:71)
08-15 00:14:21.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2291):     at com.chahalnet.myadroid.mysos.DBHelper.getAllMembers(DBHelper.java:76)
08-15 00:14:21.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2291):     at com.chahalnet.myadroid.mysos.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:38)
08-15 00:14:21.797: E/AndroidRuntime(2291):     ... 13 more
08-15 00:14:21.801: W/ActivityManager(1249):   Force finishing activity com.chahalnet.myadroid.mysos/.MainActivity
08-15 00:14:21.806: W/AudioTrack(1249): AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
08-15 00:14:21.861: D/LightsService(1249): Excessive delay setting light: 71ms
08-15 00:14:21.917: D/(1249): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa04ffcb0, tid 1452
08-15 00:14:21.943: E/EGL_emulation(933): tid 933: eglCreateSyncKHR(1237): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
08-15 00:14:22.065: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): EvaluatingState{ when=-11ms what=532486 arg1=13 target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler }
08-15 00:14:22.065: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): Checking http://clients3.google.com/generate_204 on epc.tmobile.com
08-15 00:14:22.092: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): Probably not a portal: exception java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "clients3.google.com": No address associated with hostname
08-15 00:14:22.155: D/OpenGLRenderer(1249): Render dirty regions requested: true
08-15 00:14:22.156: D/Atlas(1249): Validating map...
08-15 00:14:22.237: D/(1249): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x9fc14cd0, tid 2365
08-15 00:14:22.253: I/OpenGLRenderer(1249): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
08-15 00:14:22.280: D/OpenGLRenderer(1249): Enabling debug mode 0
08-15 00:14:22.310: W/EGL_emulation(1249): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-15 00:14:22.310: W/OpenGLRenderer(1249): Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x9e6444c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
08-15 00:14:23.043: I/Choreographer(1249): Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-15 00:14:23.079: W/ActivityManager(1249): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{14b6752e u0 com.chahalnet.myadroid.mysos/.MainActivity t41 f}
08-15 00:14:23.401: W/EGL_emulation(1506): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-15 00:14:23.401: W/OpenGLRenderer(1506): Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xb45b6f80, error=EGL_SUCCESS
08-15 00:14:24.858: I/Choreographer(1348): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-15 00:14:24.892: I/Choreographer(1249): Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-15 00:14:24.960: W/OpenGLRenderer(1506): Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...
08-15 00:14:24.960: W/OpenGLRenderer(1506): Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...
08-15 00:14:25.204: I/ActivityManager(1249): Killing 1813:com.android.music/u0a36 (adj 15): empty #17
08-15 00:14:25.291: W/libprocessgroup(1249): failed to open /acct/uid_10036/pid_1813/cgroup.procs: No such file or directory
08-15 00:14:25.301: I/Process(2291): Sending signal. PID: 2291 SIG: 9
08-15 00:14:25.305: W/AudioTrack(1249): AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
08-15 00:14:25.323: D/OpenGLRenderer(1249): endAllStagingAnimators on 0xa2dc8f80 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x9fc14eb0
08-15 00:14:25.337: E/JavaBinder(1249): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
08-15 00:14:25.338: W/InputMethodManagerService(1249): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 2291 uid 10059
08-15 00:14:25.338: E/JavaBinder(1249): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
08-15 00:14:25.341: E/JavaBinder(1383): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
08-15 00:14:25.342: E/JavaBinder(1383): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
08-15 00:14:25.379: W/InputDispatcher(1249): channel '39c085de com.chahalnet.myadroid.mysos/com.chahalnet.myadroid.mysos.MainActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
08-15 00:14:25.379: E/InputDispatcher(1249): channel '39c085de com.chahalnet.myadroid.mysos/com.chahalnet.myadroid.mysos.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
08-15 00:14:25.417: I/ActivityManager(1249): Process com.chahalnet.myadroid.mysos (pid 2291) has died
08-15 00:14:25.584: I/WindowState(1249): WIN DEATH: Window{39c085de u0 com.chahalnet.myadroid.mysos/com.chahalnet.myadroid.mysos.MainActivity}
08-15 00:14:25.584: W/InputDispatcher(1249): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '39c085de com.chahalnet.myadroid.mysos/com.chahalnet.myadroid.mysos.MainActivity (server)'
08-15 00:14:25.607: W/AudioTrack(1249): AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
08-15 00:14:27.110: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): EvaluatingState{ when=-18ms what=532486 arg1=14 target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler }
08-15 00:14:27.110: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): Checking http://clients3.google.com/generate_204 on epc.tmobile.com
08-15 00:14:27.186: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): Probably not a portal: exception java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "clients3.google.com": No address associated with hostname
08-15 00:14:32.200: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): EvaluatingState{ when=-14ms what=532486 arg1=15 target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler }
08-15 00:14:32.200: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): Checking http://clients3.google.com/generate_204 on epc.tmobile.com
08-15 00:14:32.230: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): Probably not a portal: exception java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "clients3.google.com": No address associated with hostname
08-15 00:14:37.250: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): EvaluatingState{ when=-20ms what=532486 arg1=16 target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler }
08-15 00:14:37.251: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): Checking http://clients3.google.com/generate_204 on epc.tmobile.com
08-15 00:14:37.285: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): Probably not a portal: exception java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "clients3.google.com": No address associated with hostname
08-15 00:14:42.300: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): EvaluatingState{ when=-14ms what=532486 arg1=17 target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler }
08-15 00:14:42.300: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): Checking http://clients3.google.com/generate_204 on epc.tmobile.com
08-15 00:14:42.333: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): Probably not a portal: exception java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "clients3.google.com": No address associated with hostname
08-15 00:14:47.351: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): EvaluatingState{ when=-18ms what=532486 arg1=18 target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler }
08-15 00:14:47.352: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): Checking http://clients3.google.com/generate_204 on epc.tmobile.com
08-15 00:14:47.383: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): Probably not a portal: exception java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "clients3.google.com": No address associated with hostname
08-15 00:14:52.400: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): EvaluatingState{ when=-17ms what=532486 arg1=19 target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler }
08-15 00:14:52.400: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): Checking http://clients3.google.com/generate_204 on epc.tmobile.com
08-15 00:14:52.432: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): Probably not a portal: exception java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "clients3.google.com": No address associated with hostname
08-15 00:14:57.450: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): EvaluatingState{ when=-19ms what=532486 arg1=20 target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler }
08-15 00:14:57.450: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): Checking http://clients3.google.com/generate_204 on epc.tmobile.com
08-15 00:14:57.469: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): Probably not a portal: exception java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "clients3.google.com": No address associated with hostname
08-15 00:15:02.490: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): EvaluatingState{ when=-21ms what=532486 arg1=21 target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler }
08-15 00:15:02.490: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): Checking http://clients3.google.com/generate_204 on epc.tmobile.com
08-15 00:15:02.506: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): Probably not a portal: exception java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "clients3.google.com": No address associated with hostname
08-15 00:15:07.524: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): EvaluatingState{ when=-17ms what=532486 arg1=22 target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler }
08-15 00:15:07.524: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): Checking http://clients3.google.com/generate_204 on epc.tmobile.com
08-15 00:15:07.563: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): Probably not a portal: exception java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "clients3.google.com": No address associated with hostname
08-15 00:15:37.146: D/ConnectivityService(1249): reportBadNetwork(NetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - 100]) by 10007
08-15 00:15:37.150: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): OfflineState{ when=-5ms what=532488 arg1=10007 target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler }
08-15 00:15:37.151: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): DefaultState{ when=-5ms what=532488 arg1=10007 target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler }
08-15 00:15:37.151: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): Forcing reevaluation
08-15 00:15:37.151: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): EvaluatingState{ when=-1ms what=532486 arg1=23 target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler }
08-15 00:15:37.151: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): Checking http://clients3.google.com/generate_204 on epc.tmobile.com
08-15 00:15:37.172: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): Probably not a portal: exception java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "clients3.google.com": No address associated with hostname
08-15 00:15:42.191: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): EvaluatingState{ when=-18ms what=532486 arg1=24 target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler }
08-15 00:15:42.191: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): Checking http://clients3.google.com/generate_204 on epc.tmobile.com
08-15 00:15:42.212: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): Probably not a portal: exception java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "clients3.google.com": No address associated with hostname
08-15 00:15:47.230: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): EvaluatingState{ when=-18ms what=532486 arg1=25 target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler }
08-15 00:15:47.231: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): Checking http://clients3.google.com/generate_204 on epc.tmobile.com
08-15 00:15:47.246: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): Probably not a portal: exception java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "clients3.google.com": No address associated with hostname
08-15 00:15:52.261: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): EvaluatingState{ when=-15ms what=532486 arg1=26 target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler }
08-15 00:15:52.262: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): Checking http://clients3.google.com/generate_204 on epc.tmobile.com
08-15 00:15:52.302: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): Probably not a portal: exception java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "clients3.google.com": No address associated with hostname
08-15 00:15:57.321: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): EvaluatingState{ when=-19ms what=532486 arg1=27 target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler }
08-15 00:15:57.322: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): Checking http://clients3.google.com/generate_204 on epc.tmobile.com
08-15 00:15:57.362: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): Probably not a portal: exception java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "clients3.google.com": No address associated with hostname
08-15 00:16:02.382: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): EvaluatingState{ when=-19ms what=532486 arg1=28 target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler }
08-15 00:16:02.382: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): Checking http://clients3.google.com/generate_204 on epc.tmobile.com
08-15 00:16:02.419: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): Probably not a portal: exception java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "clients3.google.com": No address associated with hostname
08-15 00:16:07.445: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): EvaluatingState{ when=-26ms what=532486 arg1=29 target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler }
08-15 00:16:07.445: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): Checking http://clients3.google.com/generate_204 on epc.tmobile.com
08-15 00:16:27.531: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): Probably not a portal: exception java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "clients3.google.com": No address associated with hostname
08-15 00:16:32.552: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): EvaluatingState{ when=-20ms what=532486 arg1=30 target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler }
08-15 00:16:32.552: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): Checking http://clients3.google.com/generate_204 on epc.tmobile.com
08-15 00:16:52.653: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): Probably not a portal: exception java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "clients3.google.com": No address associated with hostname
08-15 00:16:57.673: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): EvaluatingState{ when=-19ms what=532486 arg1=31 target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler }
08-15 00:16:57.673: D/NetworkMonitorNetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (UMTS) - null](1249): Checking http://clients3.google.com/generate_204 on epc.tmobile.com
```

Comment: Please post your stack trace, and indicate what lines in that stack trace refer to lines from the source code that you have in your question.

Comment: Try uninstalling and reinstalling your app. The stack trace suggests that your database file is corrupt for some reason. That's probably due to the bug-riddled code that you are using for packaging a database with your app. I suggest that you [use `SQLiteAssetHelper` instead](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper).

Comment: Any other alternative because I am unable to import the same file in my DB Browser.
While importing also getting error "invalid file format" exception and "Sqlite corrupt exception" and unable to open same file.